# Apagar tudo exceto o menor por dia

Tags: php, mysql

Eu estou com um problema de espaço e há muitas coisas inuteis sendo armazenadas, mas que são uteis durante o mesmo dia (irá entender).

**Problema real:**

Existem mais de 2 milhões de "linhas" e isso está ocupando mais de 1.1GB, estou usando um servidor de alta disponibilidade, enfim, isso não permite alterar a capacidade fácilmente, além de haver custos

**Solução para o problema:**

Apagar dados que não forem o menor baseado no dia, porém a data é DATETIME e preciso igualar ao DATE. Este processo iria ocorrer todos os dias, para eliminar os dados do dia anterior (mas, como já existem dados, teria que eliminar todos os antigos também).

**Explicação de como funciona:**

O site salva diversos dados de um produto diversas vezes ao dia.
Imagine o produto com o id "999".

Estes dados ("duplicados") **são úteis** durante o mesmo dia (ou seja, todos os dados de hoje devem existir), por isso não posso simplesmente verificar se já existe um maior hoje e impedir a inserção, pois deve ter esta "duplicação".

> Existe:

```
      id | Prod | Preco | Data
(id auto) | 999 | 99.99 | 2015-01-25 12:31:00
(id auto) | 999 | 89.99 | 2015-01-25 11:00:00
(id auto) | 999 | 78.99 | 2015-01-25 03:37:00
(id auto) | 999 | 98.99 | 2015-01-24 11:30:00
(id auto) | 999 | 74.99 | 2015-01-24 17:37:00
(id auto) | 999 | 79.99 | 2015-01-23 02:39:00
```

> Desejo que exista apenas:

```
      id | Prod | Preco | Data
(id auto) | 999 | 78.99 | 2015-01-25 03:37:00
(id auto) | 999 | 74.99 | 2015-01-24 17:37:00
(id auto) | 999 | 79.99 | 2015-01-23 02:39:00
```

**O que eu tentei pensar:**

Preciso de algo que selecione tudo que não for o menor e que esteja no mesmo dia.

Isto aqui está extremamente estranho, mas diz a real ideia:

```
$PegaIDMenor = SELECT id FROM tabela WHERE Preco = (SELECT MIN(Preco) FROM tabela WHERE Data LIKE '2015-01-25%' AND Prod = '999') AND Data LIKE '2015-01-25%' AND Prod = '999' LIMIT 1

// Exemplo apenas, logico que terá que existir funções de query!

$EliminaMaiores = DELETE FROM tabela WHERE id != ' $id ' AND Data LIKE '2015-01-25%' AND Prod = '999'
```

Eu pensei na data ir alterando em loop e verificando, mas acredito que deve haver alguma função melhor, somente utilizando MySQL para executar mesma tarefa, além de melhor performance.

Acho que ficou claro o que estou precisando.
Lembrando, não preciso de SELECT e sim de DELETE!

Comment: use o http://sqlfiddle.com/ para criar um teste

Comment: Você quer deletar tudo que não for o menor preço do dia especifico?

Comment: Sim, mas não por dia espeficio, mas sim sempre, todos os dias existentes. Por dia cada produto deve permanecer apenas um um dado, aquele que possua o menor preço.

Comment: O primeiro problema é que está em `DATETIME` e é preciso selecionar por `DATE` (função de `LIKE` é extremamente lento, mesmo com index). O outro problema é localizar qual é o menor por dia e por produto, para que não seja excluído. Uma outra ideia que tive, mas não consigo construir seria pegar o `ID` do `MIN()` por `GROUP BY prod`, assim teria o `ID` de todos os menores valores por produto (adicionando o `WHERE Data LIKE` teria de um dia especifico). Depois `DELETE` usando `NOT IN` destes IDs anteriores usando WHERE Data Like. Usando o PHP para criar um loop de data, apagando data por data.

Comment: Se conseguir algo do dia especifico já seria válido, porque só criar um loop para "mudar o dia especifico".

Comment: Porque não usa `DAY(Data)` ? A função `DAY` retorna o dia especificado, você poderia comparar por exemplo, `WHERE DAY(Data) = 26`

Comment: Isso também pode  ser utilizado, já havia lido sobre isso. Não sei qual seria melhor (em questão de velocidade), porque o DAY iria pegar e "converter" todos os dias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu não sei quanto a performasse, mas a sql vai deletar todos os preços que não forem o menor preço de cada produto em dias menores que hoje. Alguns where devem melhorar a performasse.

```
DELETE `precos`
FROM `precos` 
left join ( 
    SELECT max(id) id
    from precos
    inner join (
        SELECT date(Data) d, Prod pid, min(Preco) p FROM `precos` 
        WHERE 1
        group by date(Data), Prod
    ) mp on date(precos.data) = mp.d and precos.Prod = mp.pid and mp.p = precos.Preco
    group by date(Data), Prod
) save_data on save_data.id = precos.id
where 
save_data.id is null
and date(Data) < CURDATE();
```

Recomendo não rodar em produção antes de alguns testes hahaha. 
Boa sorte

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro que você faça o seguinte.

Crie uma tabela para auxiliar no processamento com o select abaixo

```
select produto, date(datetime), min(preco) from tabela group by produto, date(datetime)
```

Desta forma, terá em uma tabela todos os preços que quer ficar
Depois, faça um left para deletar

```
delete pc from preco pc left join auxiliar aux on pc.produto = aux.produto and date(pc.datetime)=aux.date and pc.preco = aux.preco where aux.produto is null
```

quando você usa o comando left, tudo que nao tiver relacao com a outra tabela será igual nulo. Desta forma, quando você usa o where produto da tabela auxiliar igual a nulo, voce remove todas as linhas que nao fazem referencia.

Antes de executar o DELETE, faça o SELECT e veja se o resultado sao as linhas que você deseja realmente excluir